# REST call :Connection timed out

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have a REST URL say - http://testing.com/account/v1/person/21324

When I call from the browser, I get a JSON response in my browser. But when I call it from a Java call(using `HttpURLConnection`), it throws an exception "Connection Timed out".

What is the difference between both the request.

Code below:

```
private static final String targetURL =
        "http://testing.com/account/v1/person/21324";
URL restServiceURL = new URL(targetURL);

HttpURLConnection httpConnection =
        (HttpURLConnection) restServiceURL.openConnection();
httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    throw new RuntimeException("HTTP GET Request Failed with Error code : "
            + httpConnection.getResponseCode());
}
```

Comment: Just guessing here, did you use the correct port in the HttpURLConnection request?

Comment: I have added the code in my question